# Adding another roughness to hair

Tags: scripting, particles, hair

I have been using yeti and xgen for hair and fur and they allow users to add multiple scraggle or roughness to the hair.For example a less frequency scraggle to generate some randomness in the hair and a high frequency scraggle to make the hair slightly frizzy.
I know this is not possible with the current hair system in blender but is there any hack to do it??

I know this might sound silly but how difficult it is code to this? I mean can you not copy the code that is there for the roughness and kinda add one more on top of it?

Comment: Have you checked out the new Principled Hair BSDF (shader?): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNlGsmZ6osk

Comment: Heyy that is the shader... I was talking about adding roughness on the mesh. As in ups and downs on the hair strands.